# Controlling array of fans

Tags: linux, cooling

So I'm building a stack of Pi's and the case I'm buying comes with four fans. I want to use a Pi Zero (ideally, but whichever one will work is fine) to control all the fans but I have no clue if this is possible or how to go about doing this.

Here is the link to the case with the fans.
https://www.c4labs.com/product/8-slot-stackable-cluster-case-raspberry-pi-3b-an‌​d-other-single-board-computers-color-options/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The fans are designed to be on when the Pis are on.

If you want to switch them on and off under software control you will need to write the software, add additional hardware, and change the fan power wiring (e.g a transistor per fan to switch the power on and off).

Comment: Not sure why there was a downvote. The product page says the fans are meant to connect to physical pins 4 and 6 which is 5v and ground. It’s certainly possible to control them with gpio of a pi zero but it would take relays or transistors and either separate power or pull the 5v from 4 different pi’s based on the relay or transistor status.